# How should I build my database/models in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, database-design, laravel-8

My app has several projects. Every project has members with different fixed roles and a member can be listed under several roles for the same project (important!). How should I structure my database/models?

I want it to look like this:

**Projects page** (see that some members can be listed twice under the same project)

```
Project 1
    Gardeners
        John Doe
        Lisa Smith
    Janitors
        Eric Black
        John Doe
    Pool keepers
        Bella Johnson

Project 2
    Gardeners
        Lisa Smith
    Janitors
        Bella Johnson
        John Doe
        Lisa Smith
```

**Members page**

```
Bella Johnson
    Janitor
    Pool keeper
Eric Black
    Janitor
John Doe
    Gardener
    Janitor
Lisa Smith
    Gardener
    Janitor
```

---

#### My thinking about database structure

**projects**

- `id`
- `title`

**members**

- `id`
- `name`

**roles**

- `id`
- `name`

**member_role**

- `id`
- `member_id`
- `role_id`

**member_role_project**

- `id`
- `member_role_id`
- `project_id`

I could also go with this instead of `member_role_project` above, but since I need a relationship for `member_role`, it seems redundant:

**member_project_role**

- `id`
- `member_id`
- `project_id`
- `role_id`

When I load my projects page, can I lazy load everything in one go in Laravel or do I need to fetch all events, loop through and fetch all roles, loop through and fetch all members? Lots of queries. What's the right approach? Thanks!

Comment: Disregardin `member_project_role` and using `member_role_project`, I think this is the correct approach, but have in mind that if the `user` updates his/her `role`, you will also had to account to do a check on your `member_role_project` because maybe you end up with a wrong role (because of its update)

Comment: One recommendation I have is to not name `member_xxxxxxx`, as you have `users` and not `members`, it will only contribute with confusion.

Comment: @matiaslauriti thank you, just to confirm, your vote is to go with `member_role_project`? Also, I meant member, not user. It’s updated. Thanks!

Comment: Yes ! `member_role_project` would mean `member_roles related to projects`.