# Should I use BelongsToMany, hasManyThrough or join?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

This is what I want to generate (please note that a member has fixed roles and can show up under multiple roles in the same project):

```
Project 1
    Gardeners
        John Doe
        Lisa Smith
    Janitors
        Eric Black
        John Doe
    Pool keepers
        Bella Johnson

Project 2
    Gardeners
        Lisa Smith
    Janitors
        Bella Johnson
        John Doe
        Lisa Smith
```

Database:

**projects**

- `id`
- `title`

**members**

- `id`
- `name`

**roles**

- `id`
- `name`

**member_role**

- `id`
- `member_id`
- `role_id`

**member_role_project**

- `id`
- `member_role_id`
- `project_id`

Is there a better approach than below?

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function memberRoles(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MemberRole::class, 'member_role_project', 'project_id', 'member_role_id');
    }
    public function members(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->memberRoles()->with('Member', 'Role');
    }
}
```

---

```
$projects = Project::with('members')->get();
$data = collect([]);

foreach ($projects as $project) {
    $roles = collect([]);
    foreach ($project->members as $role) {
        if (!$roles->contains('id', $role->Role->id)) {
            $roles->push($role->Role);
        }
    }
    $item = [
        'project' => $project,
        'roles' => $roles->map(function ($role) use ($project) {
            return [
                'title' => $role->name,
                'members' => collect($project->members->where('role_id', $role->id))->sortBy('member.name')
            ];
        })
    ];

    $data->push($item);
}
```

---

It seems like there must be a way easier approach than this? The pivot table referencing another pivot table makes my brain hurt, but hopefully Laravel has a magic trick for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having two pivot tables, you could do this with a single table. Let's say we name this table `permissions`. The structure would look something:

```
permissions: id, member_id, role_id, project_id
```

It is sort of a three-way many-to-many relation for which I often use a separate model.

**Member, Role, Project:**

```php
function permissions() {
   return $this->hasMany(Permission::class);
}
```

**Permission:**

```php
function member() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
}

function role() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
}

function project() {
   return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

Then you can query like so:

```php
$user->permissions()->where('project_id', $projectId)->first()->role();

foreach ($project->permissions as $permission) {
    $role = $permission->role;
    $member = $permission->member;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually started by trying to find out if it's better with 2 pivots or a 3 way table: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67326374/how-should-i-build-my-database-models-in-laravel?noredirect=1#comment119003667_67326374

Comment: When I tried 3 way last time I got into trouble with not being able to use attach on my seeder and things like that, are there built-in solutions in Laravel for 3 foreign keys too to get around that or do I enter custom query land at that point? In your example is `Permission` an extension of `Model` or `Pivot`? Thanks again!

Comment: And last thing, would it be possible to show an example of how you would query to get the data for my example list with the two projects at the top? Would be very helpful! I'm brand new to this.

Comment: I also want to add that the table `member_role` is used to keep track of the member's roles, which is why I was trying to figure out if a 3 way table would be redundant, but I guess there are pros and cons with both solutions.

Comment: Laravel doesn't have a built-in solution for this I'm afraid. That's why we have to settle for hacky solutions. But I find this to be the best approach for such situations. And yes, the `Permission` should extend `Model`

Comment: Cool! I'll try to rewrite my my tables and models your way and see if I can figure it out. It looks a lot cleaner than what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You should be able to structure it the way you want by using `with()` and `groupBy()` in some way. I can't exactly test it out as it will take some setting up. But I'm sure you'll figure it out. :)

Comment: Yes I'll give it a shot! It looks logical to me. :) Big thanks again!

Comment: I tried it out and I went from 10 queries to 26 and increasing with more data hehe :) How do I avoid the N + 1 problem with this approach? Doesn’t your foreach make 2 database requests per loop iteration? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, It does. It was meant as a minimal example. I'd probably do `$project->permissions()->with(['role', 'member'])->get()` or something like that. Also, you can probably use `map()` without having to loop.